# ThreadSanitizer in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, thread-sanitizer

I am trying to build my project and run an executable in a different machine where I can see thread related issues (if exist). I am using VS2019 and providing `-fsanitize=thread -fPIE -pie -g` options in the `Configuration Properties->Debugging->Command Arguments`.
When I run the .exe file, I don't see any generated file which I suppose should have been generated.
Am I providing wrong arguments to the compiler or what is wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- *Configuration Properties->Debugging->Command Arguments* is a wrong place for compiler options. They should go to *Configuration Properties->C/C++->Command Line->Additional options*
- These options you want to pass are not supported neither by MSVC compiler (Visual C++), nor by clang-cl (Clang under Windows that mimic MSVC)
- MSVC does not have ThreadSanitizer at all. (`-fsanitize=address` is available though)